# What's the meaning of "hold out"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following is a subtitle of an article titled *Why I refuse to text message*:

> I don't care how convenient it is, or how many friends pity me for my decision. I'm holding out -- here's why

What does *hold out* mean above? I've looked it up in the dictionaries, but none of the definitions provided seem to fit the context.

Comment: See also the noun form: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/holdout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Holding out can mean purposefully not participating, 
e.g. *I'm holding out on swimming until it gets a bit warmer.*

[The free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/holding+out)'s third meaning of "holding out" clarifies: To continue to resist. *The defending garrison held out for a month.*

Their [idiom dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hold+out) further explains:

**hold out (for someone or something)** to strive to wait for someone or something. *I will hold out for someone who can do the job better than the last person we interviewed. I want to hold out for a better offer.*

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it means :

1. *I'm holding on to my beliefs and won't text message, here's why*
2. *I won't change my mind about texting, here's why*

Answer (score 0):

Verb: There is an expectation expressed in "hold out" that things will improve, i.e. that the currently-proposed solution is not good enough, and that something better will come along (or be found) in good time.

Noun: A "holdout" is (among other things) a committed non-participant in some event or change; someone who objects to participating, and will not be persuaded to take part. In some cases, an alternative method of getting them either to *buy in* or to leave the situation has to be found; in others, if they don't exert a substantial influence, it may be possible to ignore them.

Answer (score -4):

Every Body
The Phrase "Hold Out" means Wait or "Holding Out "  means Waiting too 
An Example to Understand : when your friend is going out W U and Yo are too late you Shall tell Him To hold out like : Hold out,Jack. 
I think you understood know :)

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question. Did you read the question?

Comment: I think @ClaraHani is referring to a local idiom that is not common to the rest of us.  An imperative to "Hold Out!" in her proposed usage translates to a command/request to "Wait!".
Using it as an imperative is not the common usage in American English (AmE).